# What do $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty S_n$ and $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty S_n$ mean?

Tags: probability, statistics, elementary-set-theory, notation

> In some cases, we will have to consider the union or the intersection of several, even infinitely many sets, defined in the obvious way. For example, if for every positive integer $n$, we are given a set $S_n$, then
>   $$\bbox[border:1px solid red]{\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty S_n}=S_1\cup S_2\cup\cdots=\{x\mid x\in S_n\text{ for some }n\},$$
>   and
>   $$\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty S_n=S_1\cap S_2\cap\cdots=\{x\mid x\in S_n\text{ for all }n\}.$$
>   Two sets are said to be disjoint if their intersection is empty. More generally, several sets are said to be **disjoint** if no two of them have a common element. A collection of sets is said to be a **partition** of a set $S$ if the sets in the collection are disjoint and their union is $S$.

Normally what I know is that you can make a union or an intersection between only two sets. In this expression, there is a big union of sets. I'm asking about the meaning of this expression – what does it mean? What does the infinity sign do at the top?

Things are even more complicated with De Morgan's laws, which use the same expression:

> Two particularly useful properties are given by **De Morgan's laws** which state that
>   $$\left(\bigcup_nS_n\right)^c=\bigcap_nS_n^c,\quad\quad\quad\quad\left(\bigcap_nS_n\right)^c=\bigcup_nS_n^c.$$

Anyone who can explain to me the expression or De Morgan's laws would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 27):

The equation where you've enclosed the first part in red is the *definition* of the $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} S_n$ notation.

It works just like sum notation does:
$$ \sum_{n=a}^{b} f(n) \quad\text{means}\quad f(a)+f(a+1)+\cdots+f(b-1)+f(b) $$
and
$$ \bigcup_{n=a}^{b} f(n) \quad\text{means}\quad f(a)\cup f(a+1)\cup\cdots\cup f(b-1)\cup f(b) $$
$$ \bigcap_{n=a}^{b} f(n) \quad\text{means}\quad f(a)\cap f(a+1)\cap\cdots\cap f(b-1)\cap f(b) $$

When the upper limit is $\infty$ it means a union of infinitely many sets:
$$ \bigcup_{n=a}^{\infty} f(n) \quad\text{means}\quad f(a)\cup f(a+1)\cup\cdots $$
whose precise meaning is defined in the explanation you quote.

Comment: Think of the infinity sign on the top as playing the same role here as it does in a sum $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n$.

Comment: One important difference with the $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n)$ notation is that $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty S_n$ is always defined (provided the sets $S_n$ are), without any requirement of "convergence" as is the case for infinite sums.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Sure. But even the sum is always defined (though possibly infinite) when the items being summed are all nonnegative.

Comment: Please excuse me since I haven't used math or statistics for a very very long time. So What I understood from your example using summation(sigma) sign. That the upper part is the boundary of the range or the end condition and the lower part (n=1) is the start of the collection. So $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n)$ means that the summation of outputs for each parameter passed to f in this case n where n starts with one and ends with $\infty$. An example would be $\sum_{n=1}^3 f(n) = f(1) + f(2) + f(3)$, is that correct?

Comment: @OmarA.Shaban: Yes.

Comment: In the case of "$\bigcup_n$" with just $n$ ranging over $\mathbb N$ and no infinity sign, I've seen $\sum_{p\textrm{ prime}}$ which is a similar restriction of an index to a set.

Answer (score 3):

Considering de Morgan's laws, they become basic principles of handling negation in the presence of quantifiers in logic. Let's first state more formally
$$
  x\in\bigcup_{i\in\Bbb N}S_n \iff \exists n\in\Bbb N: x\in S_n
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
  x\in\bigcap_{i\in\Bbb N}S_n \iff \forall n\in\Bbb N: x\in S_n.
$$
Now the law $\left(\bigcup_{i\in\Bbb N}S_n\right)^c=\bigcap_{i\in\Bbb N}{S_n}^c$ becomes, remembering that set equality just means one is member of the left hand side if and only if one is member of the right hand side,
$$
  \lnot(\exists n\in\Bbb N: x\in S_n)\iff \forall n\in\Bbb N: \lnot(x\in S_n).
$$
Similarly $\left(\bigcap_{i\in\Bbb N}S_n\right)^c=\bigcup_{i\in\Bbb N}{S_n}^c$ becomes
$$
  \lnot(\forall n\in\Bbb N: x\in S_n)\iff \exists n\in\Bbb N: \lnot(x\in S_n).
$$
These are nothing more or less than the rules for handling negation of existentially or universally quantified phrases (in the particular case of quantification over$~\Bbb N$, but one could replace it by any set).