# Reading Set Notation with Multiple Intersections

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I am going through a [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0212212.pdf) that deals with Voronoi cell partition. I have difficulty in reading equation (11). Is this equation read as:

Region W = intersection of region $\bar B$ intersection with (all the intersection of half planes $S_{ij}$ such that $j:||p_i-p_j||$ is less then $R_i$?

[image]

Comment: Yes, precisely.

Comment: What @DonThousand said. I assume you meant to write $p_i$ not $o_i$ in your 2nd paragraph, "Region W = ... ?"

Comment: @DonThousand how do we read the notation inside the circular brackets? I dont think what I wrote is correct as it wont make much sense.

Comment: @BrianO yes, I will correct it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the big intersection or union sign of a set mean?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/483002/what-does-the-big-intersection-or-union-sign-of-a-set-mean)

Comment: @MarkS. yes it helps but in my case its intersection of intersections. I will try to draw it pictorially and add to the question to ensure if i have right mental picture of the equation

Comment: If you understand the notation $A\cap B$ and you understand the notation $\displaystyle{\bigcap_{j:\cdots}}C(j)$, then you can combine those two to understand $A\cap \left(\displaystyle{\bigcap_{j:\cdots}}C(j)\right)$.