# What is the meaning of this symbol, $\bigcap$, for the function of my subset?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I have an exercise regarding subsets, but I am confused with the notation, as there is a symbol $\bigcap$, like the intersection symbol, before the function of the subset and I am not sure what this means.
The whole equation is $A=\bigcap_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\{x\in \mathbb{R}^2\mid 0 \leq \|x\|_2 <4k\}$

Comment: $ \bigcap_{k\in\mathbb N}A_n=A_1\cap A_2\cap \dots \cap A_n\cap\dots$, where each $A_i$ is a set

Comment: Don't vandalize your own questions! It does not serve any purpose other than getting it closed and deleted.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the big intersection or union sign of a set mean?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/483002/what-does-the-big-intersection-or-union-sign-of-a-set-mean)

Answer (score 3):

This is just the intersection symbol. It is in the iterative form, much as the $\sum$ symbol indicates an iterated sum. It happens that the only difference from the infix notation is that $\bigcap$ is usually bigger, and usually the indexing would be beneath it (as well as above it there are limits to an integer range). It is the intersection over all $k\in N$ of the subsets of $\mathbb R^2$ described by the set builder notation. In display style you get
$$\bigcap_{k\in N}\{x\in R^2\mid 0\leq\|x\|_2<1/k\}$$